# Ayuda con problema básico de Prolog. Suma total de Areas

Tags: prolog

Tengo el siguiente problema:
 El Sr. Juan Lopez posee un terreno en forma de un triángulo rectángulo cuyos lados son: 11, 7, 11 metros. Así mismo, su vecino, del que no conoce su nombre, tiene un terreno de forma triangular con medidas: 11,7.5, 11 metros. El Sr. Vazquez también tiene un terreno de forma cuadrada de 11 metros cada lado. La fórmula para obtener el área de un triángulo rectángulo es base por altura, dividido para 2.
    ¿Cuál es el área del terreno del vecino del Sr. Lopez?
    ¿Cuánto suma el total de todas las áreas?

Me falta resolver la pregunta de la suma total de las áreas. Alguien tiene una idea de qué se podría hacer ahí?

```
posee(juanperez,terreno(triangulo(11,7,11))).
posee(vecino(juanperez),terreno(triangulo(11,7.5,11))).
posee(vazquez,terreno(cuadrado(11))).

%Semiperimetro
s(L1,L2,L3,S):- S is (L1+L2+L3)/2.

alturaL1(L1,L2,L3,Altura):-s(L1,L2,L3,S), Altura is (2/L1)*sqrt(S*(S-L1)*(S-L2)*(S-L3)).


areaTriangulo(L1,L2,L3,Area):-alturaL1(L1,L2,L3,H), Area is L1*H/2.
areaCuadrado(L1,Area):-Area is L1*L1.


areaTerreno(P,Area):-posee(P,Terreno), Terreno=terreno(cuadrado(A)),areaCuadrado(A,Area).
areaTerreno(P,Area):-posee(P,Terreno), Terreno=terreno(triangulo(A,B,C)),areaTriangulo(A,B,C,Area).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo tienes que obtener todas las respuestas del predicado `areaTerreno/2` y sumarlas. El estándar de Prolog define el predicado `findall/3` para buscar todas las respuestas de un objetivo y devolverlas en una lista:

```
findall(A, areaTerreno(_,A), L)
```

con lo que se obtendría la lista `L = [121, 36.4991, 38.7789]` en tu ejemplo.

Ahora hay que definir el predicado `sumatorio/2`, que devuelve la suma de los números de una lista. Cuando la lista está vacía el sumatorio es `0`, y en cualquier otro caso se calcula recursivamente el sumatorio de la cola y al resultado se le suma la cabeza:

```
sumatorio([],0).
suamtorio([H|T],X) :- sumatorio(T,S), X is H+S.
```

Finalmente construimos un predicado `areaTotal/2` que obtenga las áreas con `findall/3` y devuelva el sumatorio con `sumatorio/2`:

```
areaTotal(X) :- findall(A, areaTerreno(_,A), L), sumatorio(L,X).
```